# error with using strptime in c++

Tags: c++, strptime

I've tried to understand use of strptime() in c++ and to be able to do it, I write a short code :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
Test(string dtime)  
{
    string s = dtime;

    struct tm timeDate;
    strptime(s,"%y-%m-%d %H:%M", &timeDate);
    cout<<timeDate.tm_sec<<endl;
}
```

dtime will always be like *2013:03:15 16:08*. I got the error it says that :

```
Test(std::string)’:
Test.cpp:17:41: error: cannot convert ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* strptime(const char*, const char*, tm*)
```

Is there anyone to help me to solve my problem ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The declaration of `strptime` is:

```
char *strptime(const char *s, const char *format, struct tm *tm);
```

The first argument expects a `const char *`. You are passing a `std::string`

Convert `s` to a C style `char *`

```
strptime(s.c_str(),"%y-%m-%d %H:%M", &timeDate);
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Yea it solved my problem however what was the problem ? I mean Why should I need to convert s to "C style" char* strptime is a C language function and does not support string ? @Kunal

Comment: again thanks. 1 more question. I think string is already char pointer ? Am I wrong ?

Comment: `String` is not a `char *`. It is a `class` defined in the C++ standard library. `String` objects represent a sequence of characters.

Comment: @Kunal to use the code above with s="2013-19-10 03:01", and write cout<<timeDate.tm_min<<timeDate.tm_year<<endl; I got garbage and  113 always . Do you know the reason ?